# Django get current view in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

How can I get the full name of the current view (my_app.views.index) in a template in Django 1.5?

With forms, I have an object called "view" in the template which I read using a template tag.
But with DetailViews I doesn't see anything similar.

Is there a way using a custom template processor?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Situation 1:

1. I retrieve a page, for example '/foo/bar/5/edit'.
2. Django will call 'foo.views.editbar' with pk=5.
3. This view renders an template 'foo/bar_form.html'

Situation 2:

1. If I retrieve '/foo/bar/new'
2. Django will call 'foo.views.newbar'
3. This view renders the same template as above ('foo/bar_form.html')

How can I check in this template 'foo/bar_form.html', from which view it has been rendered?
The result should be one of

- 'foo.views.editbar'
- 'foo.views.newbar'

Comment: what are you trying for?

Comment: Can you explain more your question? and if it's possible put code please

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just [set attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to request object in view:

```
setattr(request, 'view', 'app.views.func')
```

and check this in template:

```
{% if request.view == 'app.views.func' %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Why would you use `setattr` instead of `getattr`. Set will set the attribute to the value passed to it.

Answer (score 22):

Type just in view

```
{% with request.resolver_match.view_name as view_name %}
    ...
    {{ view_name }}
    ...
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the requirement, but take a look at [inspect.stack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack).

```
inspect.stack()[1][3]
```

Comment: Thanks! This would work, but it's a very dirty hack. Is there really  no way to retrieve this information direcly in a middleware or templatetag?

Comment: not that I know of. I use this method so if you find one better please let me know :). Small guidance - just comment what it is doing so future you will not look puzzled at this odd code.